# Bernoulli random variables - 2 equations with 2 variables?

Tags: probability

$A$ and $B$ are two independent Bernoulli random variables with parameters Pa and Pb. Assuming that $\Pr[A < B] = 1/4$ and $\Pr[A + B \le 1] = 3/4$ calculate the values of $A$ and $B$.

I'm not sure about the terminology and the way I should solve it.
1. $\Pr[A < B] = 1/4$ - Does it mean that the probability of $A = 0$ and $B = 1$ is $1/4$?
2. $\Pr[A + B \le 1] = 3/4$ - Does it mean that that the probability of "not both of them equal 1" is $3/4$?
3. How should I approach the solution? 2 variables and 2 equations?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Nice approach. I give you some confirmations and further hints so that you can finish by yourself.

> Does it mean that the probability of $A=0$ and $B=1$ is $1/4$?

That´s true.

> $Pr[A + B ≤ 1] = 3/4$ - Does it mean that that the probability of "not
>   both of them equal 1" is $3/4?$

Yes. Here you can use the converse probability. The probability that not
both of them are equal $1$ is

$$1- P("\textrm{Both of them are equal to 1}")$$

> How should I approach the solution? 2 variables and 2 equations?

Yes, with the variables $p_a$ and $p_b$.

Comment: Thanks! not sure how can I translate it into 2 equations that make sense?

Comment: A is a bernoulli variable that means that $P(A=0)=1-p_a$. And therefore $P(B=1)=p_b$ Is this comprehensible? If yes then A and B are independent. That means $P(A=0\cap B=1)=P(A=0)\cdot P(B=1)$

Comment: (1-Pa) * Pb = 1/4 and 1-(pa*pb) = 3/4? And in this case, both equal to 1/2. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, your are correct. Congrats.

Comment: @Bob_Bobb It is welcomed that you accept an answer if there are no questions anymore.